# cordova_plugins.js missing with iOS build on phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm trying to move away from Phonegap Build, as it seems they have put a stop to that project. This is my current **config.xml** section related to plugins file I use on Phonegap build:

I'm building using:

```
phonegap build ios
```

It runs without any errors. However, when I try and run it in the simulator I see the following error:

> cordova_plugins.js: 404 not found

When I run:

```
cordova plugin list
```

I get am empty list. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ok - it seems like I may have answered my own question.

With PhoneGap Build, you simply define the plugins you want to use inside the **config.xml** (as in my opening question). However, it seems you have to manually add every one of them with the CLI version :( So:

```
cd /path/to/app/folder
phonegap plugin add whatever-plugin-name-is
```